# Add custom slug to link for WP default posts

Tags: wordpress

How can I modify default posts permalink?
E.g. www.example.com/post-slug/ i need to change to www.example.com/blog/post-slug/
I need this only for default wp posts, I have achieved the same with adding custom post type (www.example.com/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio-slug, but I hope there is a cleaner way for default wp posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) at the WordPress Codex. In the Settings → Permalinks panel you can select the custom option, then add `/blog` before the rest of your permalink structure, which would result in something like this: `/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/`.

EDIT: Adding Additional Detail

Change your rewrite from:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
```

to:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false),
```

Read more about [register_post_type Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) at the WordPress Codex.

Comment: But then it will change permalink for for my custom post types. E.g if I have custom post type /portfolio/, then when I change in Settings-> permalinks to custom: /blog/%postname%/ my custom post types will also have /blog/portfolio/post-name/

Comment: See my previous edit. You need to add `'with_front' => false`.

Comment: I have the same issue.. Could you explain more please? Where do you write the code above? I do not have any code like this to rewrite in functions.php.. thanks in advance